# ALU using Component and Process

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I'm designing simple ALU for my own that use 2 bits for `select` operations. Suppose that, my operations is as follows:

```
00 C <= A & B
01 C <= A + B
10 C <= NOT (A)
11 C <= '0' & A (7 DOWNTO 1)
```

And my `ALU` contains two register for input with load enable `LE` and one output register with load enable `LE` and output control `OC`. Firstly, I design a input register using `VHDL Module` as below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity RegIn is
    PORT (
        LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
        INPUT: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        OUTPUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end RegIn;

architecture Behavioral of RegIn is
begin
    PROCESS (LE)
    BEGIN
        IF (LE = '1') THEN
            OUTPUT <= INPUT;
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;
end Behavioral;
```

When, `LE` is high, INPUT will be place instead of OUTPUT value. I have two input register name `TEMP1` and `TEMP2`. I design output register using input register except it contains `OC` signal as buffer control. It shows in continue:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity RegOut is
    PORT (
        LE, OC: IN STD_LOGIC;
        INPUT: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        OUTPUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end RegOut;

architecture Behavioral of RegOut is
    SIGNAL INPUT_OUTPUT: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);

    COMPONENT RegIn 
        PORT (
            INPUT: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            OUTPUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            LE: IN STD_LOGIC
        );
    END COMPONENT;
begin
    RPM:
        RegIn PORT MAP (
            INPUT => INPUT,
            OUTPUT => INPUT_OUTPUT,
            LE => LE
        );

    PROCESS (OC)
    BEGIN
        IF (OC = '1') THEN
            OUTPUT <= INPUT_OUTPUT;
        ELSE
            OUTPUT <= "ZZZZZZZZ";
        END IF;
    END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

Now, I want to implement my `ALU` using code such below:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity ALU is
    Port (
        TEMP_1_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
        TEMP_2_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
        TEMP_3_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
        TEMP_3_OC: IN STD_LOGIC;

        TEMP_1_IN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
        TEMP_2_IN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);

        C: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 DOWNTO 0);

        CF: OUT STD_LOGIC;
        ZF: OUT STD_LOGIC;
        SF: OUT STD_LOGIC;

        TEMP_3_OUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
    );
end ALU;

architecture Behavioral of ALU is
    COMPONENT RegIn IS
        PORT (
            LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
            INPUT: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            OUTPUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    COMPONENT RegOut IS
        PORT (
            LE, OC: IN STD_LOGIC;
            INPUT: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            OUTPUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    END COMPONENT;

    SIGNAL TEMP_1_OUT, TEMP_2_OUT, TEMP_3_IN: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
    SIGNAL TEMP: STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 DOWNTO 0);
begin
    RTEMP1:
        RegIn PORT MAP (
            LE => TEMP_1_LE,
            INPUT => TEMP_1_IN,
            OUTPUT => TEMP_1_OUT
        );

    RTEMP2:
        RegIn PORT MAP (
            LE => TEMP_2_LE,
            INPUT => TEMP_2_IN,
            OUTPUT => TEMP_2_OUT
        );

    RTEMP3:
        RegOut PORT MAP (
            LE => TEMP_3_LE,
            OC => TEMP_3_OC,
            INPUT => TEMP_3_IN,
            OUTPUT => TEMP_3_OUT
        );

        PROCESS(TEMP_3_OC)
        BEGIN
                IF (TEMP_3_OC = '1') THEN
                    TEMP_3_IN <= TEMP_1_OUT + TEMP_2_OUT;
                ...
                END IF;
        END PROCESS;

end Behavioral;
```

In my test bench, I force TEMP_3_OC to '1' but it does not change to '1' and still is '0'.

What was wrong? How can I correct it ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You're missing some sensitivity elements on the RegIn process (LE, Input), the RegOut process (OC, INPUT_OUTPUT) and the ALU process (TEMP_3_OC, TEMP_1_OUT, TEMP_2_OUT).  Also there appears to be no REASON TEMP_3_OC is used in that process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some sensitivity elements on the RegIn process (LE, Input), the RegOut process (OC, INPUT_OUTPUT) and the ALU process (TEMP_3_OC, TEMP_1_OUT, TEMP_2_OUT).

Once you have fixed the sensitivity list elements your ALU works for the available operation ("01", C <= A + B ).

[image: ALU test bench]

The test bench I used:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture test of tb is
    component ALU is
        Port (
            TEMP_1_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
            TEMP_2_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
            TEMP_3_LE: IN STD_LOGIC;
            TEMP_3_OC: IN STD_LOGIC;

            TEMP_1_IN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);
            TEMP_2_IN: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0);

            C: IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 DOWNTO 0);

            CF: OUT STD_LOGIC;
            ZF: OUT STD_LOGIC;
            SF: OUT STD_LOGIC;

            TEMP_3_OUT: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 DOWNTO 0)
        );
    end component;
    signal LEA:         std_logic := '1';
    signal LEB:         std_logic := '1';
    signal LEC:         std_logic := '1';
    signal OUTENAB:     std_logic := '0';
    signal A:           std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :=X"21";
    signal B:           std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :=X"21";
    signal OP:           std_logic_vector(1 downto 0) := "01" ;
    signal CF:          std_logic;
    signal ZF:          std_logic;
    signal SF:          std_logic;
    signal C:           std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) ;
begin
DUT: alu port map (
            LEA,
            LEB,
            LEC,
            OUTENAB,
            A,
            B,
            OP,
            CF,
            ZF,
            SF,
            C);
STIMULUS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 20 ns;
        OUTENAB <= '1';
        wait for 20 ns;
        wait;
    end process;

end architecture;
```

For it's limited simulation, the only sensitivity list requiring patching was for RegIn.